# Test multiple columns of strings for match row-wise in R

Tags: r, string, match

As part of an attribute agreement analysis I need to figure out in how many cases the operators (x,y,z) are in perfect agreement with each other. Let's say my dataset looks like this.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x = c("Good","Average","Bad"), y = c("Good","Average","Bad"), z = c("Average","Average","Bad"))

> DT
     x       y       z
1:    Good    Good Average
2: Average Average Average
3:    Poor    Poor    Poor
4:    Poor Average    Good
```

For each row, I want to know whether the string in column x,y and z is equal.
And print the result in a new column. 
If all columns are equal it should return one.
If one or more columns have different values it should return zero.

```
     x       y       z     all.equal
1:    Good    Good Average         0
2: Average Average Average         1
3:    Poor    Poor    Poor         1
4:    Poor Average    Good         0
```

I have had success with checking if two columns are equal

```
vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl)
DT[, all.equal:= as.integer(vgrepl(x, y))]
```

I can however not get it to work with more than two columns.

Thank you very much!

Comment: table has 3 rows in the reproducible form but the prinout pasted above has 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach checks whether you have 1 or more unique values in each row:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(x = c("Good","Average","Bad"), 
                 y = c("Good","Average","Bad"), 
                 z = c("Average","Average","Bad"))

DT[, all.equal:= as.numeric(length(unique(c(x,y,z))) == 1), by=seq_len(nrow(DT))]

DT

#          x       y       z all.equal
# 1:    Good    Good Average         0
# 2: Average Average Average         1
# 3:     Bad     Bad     Bad         1
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
cols <- c("x", "y", "z")
all_same <- function(x) as.integer(all(x[1] == x[-1])) 
DT[, all.equal := apply(.SD, 1, all_same), .SDcols = cols]


#          x       y       z all.equal
# 1:    Good    Good Average         0
# 2: Average Average Average         1
# 3:     Bad     Bad     Bad         1
```